# Unable to execute Backing bean method

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Command button onclick event is not working its not invoking Banking bean Method. There are some other commandButtons like

```
action="#{editBean.editQuestionAction}" 
action="#{editBean.addNewQuestionAction}"
```

were working fine but its not in the case  of  `action="#{editBean.updateQuestionAction}"

```
<p:tab title="Questions">
                <h:outputText value="Select a project to add questions: " />
                <h:selectOneMenu id="projects_dpd" value="#{editBean.currentProject.projectId}" onchange="">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{projectBean.projects}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu><br/>

                <h:form id="listForm">
                    <p:panel id="listPanel" header="List of Questions" toggleable="false" closable="false">
                        <p:dataList paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" paginatorPosition="bottom" effect="slide"
                                    value="#{editBean.editBeanList}" var="q"
                                    paginator="true" rows="5" effectSpeed="fast"
                                    paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

                            <p:column>
                                <p:commandButton action="#{editBean.**editQuestionAction**}" update="editPanel" title="Edit Question" image="edit">
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{q}" target="#{editBean.editQuestion}" />
                                </p:commandButton>
                                <p:spacer width="30" height="30" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{q.question.questionId} -> #{q.question.questionText} ->"/> <b><h:outputText value="#{q.question.questionType}" /></b>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataList>
                        <p:commandButton value="New Question !!" action="#{editBean.**addNewQuestionAction**}" update="editPanel" />
                        <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Home Page !!" action="#{indexBean.**gotoHomePage}**" />
                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center" scrollable="true">
                    <p:panel id="editPanel" header="Edit Section" toggleable="false" closable="false" >
                        <h:form id="form">
                            <table cellspacing="20">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h:outputLabel value="Question Text:" /></td>
                                    <td><p:inputTextarea id="questionText"  required="true" value="#{editBean.editQuestion.question.questionText}" autoResize="true" effectDuration="400" maxHeight="100" /></td>                                <td><p:message for="questionText" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Review:</td>
                                    <td><p:inputTextarea id="reviewText" required="true" value="#{editBean.editQuestion.question.reviewText}" autoResize="true" effectDuration="400" maxHeight="100" /></td>
                                    <td><p:message for="reviewText" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Option Type:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:selectOneRadio label="Option Type" value="#{editBean.editQuestion.question.optionType}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Currency" itemValue="currency" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hours" itemValue="hours" />
                                        </h:selectOneRadio>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Question Type:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:selectOneRadio label="Question Type" value="#{editBean.editQuestion.question.questionType}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mandatory" itemValue="mandatory" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Linked" itemValue="linked" />
                                        </h:selectOneRadio>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox label="Hide Weight until Review !!" value="#{editBean.editQuestion.question.hideWeight}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Hide Weight Until Review</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Options:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p:panel header="Add Option">
                                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="grid">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="Text : " for="txt_title"></h:outputLabel>
                                                <p:inputText id="txt_title"
                                                             value="#{editBean.placeHolderForOption.optionText}" />

                                                <h:outputLabel value="Weight : " for="txt_author"></h:outputLabel>
                                                <p:inputText id="txt_author"
                                                             value="#{editBean.placeHolderForOption.weight}" />

                                                <p:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset"/>
                                                <p:commandButton value="Add" update="options @parent"
                                                                 action="#{editBean.initOption}" >
                                                    <p:collector value="#{editBean.placeHolderForOption}"
                                                                 addTo="#{editBean.editQuestion.options}" />
                                                </p:commandButton>
                                            </h:panelGrid>
                                        </p:panel>

                                        <p:outputPanel id="options">
                                            <p:dataTable value="#{editBean.editQuestion.options}" var="opt">
                                                <p:column headerText="Text" style="width:150px">
                                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                                        <f:facet name="output">
                                                            <h:outputText value="#{opt.optionText}" />
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                            <h:inputText value="#{opt.optionText}" />
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column headerText="Weight" style="width:150px">
                                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                                        <f:facet name="output">
                                                            <h:outputText value="#{opt.weight}" />
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                            <h:inputText value="#{opt.weight}" />
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column headerText="Linked Question" style="width:150px">
                                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                                        <f:facet name="output">
                                                            <h:outputText value="#{opt.linkedQuestionId}" />
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{opt.linkedQuestionId}">
                                                                <f:selectItems value="#{editBean.linkedQuestionIds}" />
                                                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column headerText="Display Order" style="width:150px">
                                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                                        <f:facet name="output">
                                                            <h:outputText value="#{opt.displayOrder}" />
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                            <h:inputText value="#{opt.displayOrder}" />
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column>
                                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                                        <h:outputText value="Operation" />
                                                    </f:facet>
                                                    <p:commandLink value="Remove" update="form:options" process="@this">
                                                        <p:collector value="#{opt}"
                                                                     removeFrom="#{editBean.editQuestion.options}" />
                                                    </p:commandLink>
                                                    <p:spacer width="10" />
                                                    <p:rowEditor />
                                                </p:column>
                                            </p:dataTable>
                                        </p:outputPanel>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Update Question" action="#{editBean.updateQuestionAction}"
                                             rendered="#{editBean.operation eq 'edit'}" />

                            <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Add Question" update="msgs listForm:listPanel" action="#{editBean.saveQuestion}"
                                             rendered="#{editBean.operation eq 'add'}">
                                <p:collector value="#{editBean.editQuestion}"
                                             addTo="#{editBean.editBeanList}" />
                            </p:commandButton>

                            <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Delete Question" update="msgs listForm:listPanel" action="#{editBean.deleteQuestionAction}"
                                             rendered="#{editBean.operation eq 'edit'}">
                                <p:collector value="#{editBean.editQuestion}"
                                             removeFrom="#{editBean.editBeanList}" />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </h:form>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:tab>
```

Its not getting executing when i click on button

```
 @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class EditBean {

        @ManagedProperty(value = "#{questionDao}")
        private QuestionDao questionDao;
        private String operation;
        private QuestionHelper editQuestion;
        private SelectItem[] linkedQuestionIds;
        private List<QuestionHelper> linkedQuestions = new ArrayList<QuestionHelper>();
        private List<QuestionHelper> allQuestions = new ArrayList<QuestionHelper>();
 public void editQuestionAction() {
        operation = "edit";
    }

    public void deleteQuestionAction() {
        questionDao.delete(editQuestion.getQuestion());
        listBean.getListOfQuestions().remove(editQuestion);
        addNewQuestionAction();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Question: ", "Question Deleted !"));
    }

    public void updateQuestionAction() {
        editQuestion.getQuestion().getOptionses().clear();
        for (Options o : editQuestion.getOptions()) {
            o.setQuestions(editQuestion.getQuestion());
            editQuestion.getQuestion().getOptionses().add(o);
        }
        getQuestionDao().update(editQuestion.getQuestion());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Question: ", "Question Updated !"));
    }
```

Comment: show the bean definition

Comment: Its a very big File i cant include here

Comment: @madhav the whole file may be big, but you can extract the relevant bits

Comment: I had updated the code, Please let what would halting execution

Comment: can you try replacing it with `h:commandButton` and see if it works?

Comment: Ya i tried, h:commandButton also not working.

Comment: anything in the logs? javascript issues?

Comment: @madhav: There is a lot of noise in the code. For example, is this `<h:selectOneMenu>` really relevant to the problem? If you remove this, does the problem still occur? Then it is likely totally irrelevant to the problem and you can just keep it away. Do the same for other pieces in the code such as `<p:spacer>`, `<table cellspacing>`, etc. You need to strip as much as possible noise and end up with a **minimum** necessary code for the view (XHTML file) and the model (javabean class) which still reproduces the problem and finally post it here.

Comment: Thanks alot, (Bozho,BalusC) as U said, code is not making clear view. I will Try to remove unnecessary part, than i will post it here again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I found answer for my question, The command button is not working because of rendered tag and Request scope of managed bean , as on every subsequent request after pressing command button my request scoped (iseditable ) is getting resetting. When i made it Session scoped its working Fine.