# p:commandbutton is not calling manage bean method

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have the follow modal form in Bootstrap, where the user insert data for add a new line but the p:commandbutton never executes lineaBean.insertar() and I don't know what it's doing this when I have a delete modal form that looks equal and works like a charm... any ideas? Here is my code:

```
<!-- Bootstrap trigger to open modal -->
    <div class="hide fade modal" id="insertar-linea">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Alta de linea</h3>
          </div>
         <h:form class="form-horizontal well" id="form-insertar-linea">
          <div class="modal-body">                                                          
              <fieldset>                                                              
                    <h4>Número: </h4><h:inputText id="numero-form" class="validate[required]" value="#{lineasBean.numero}"></h:inputText>
                    <h4>Fecha Validacion: </h4><h:inputText id="fecha-form" class="validate[required]" value="#{lineasBean.fechaFact}"></h:inputText>
                    <h4>Publico: </h4>
                    <h:selectOneRadio id="publico-form" value="#{lineasBean.publico}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="SI" itemValue="y"/> 
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="NO" itemValue="n"/>
                    </h:selectOneRadio>                                                                                           
              </fieldset>   
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</a>
              <p:commandButton id="okInsertar" onclick="if($('#form-insertar-linea').validationEngine('validate')===false){return false;}"
                               styleClass="btn btn-primary ok" value="Ok" action="#{lineasBean.insertar()}"
                               oncomplete="checkCRUD(xhr, status, args)"/>                                                                                                                                                               
            </div> 
          </h:form>

        </div>
```

Comment: Is the `onclick` of `p:commandButton` blocking? If you remove the JavaScript code inside it, does it change something?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution, I was setting up 'fechaFact' on my bean as Date type when I was passing a String... so I make a SimpleDateFormat for parse the String into Date in the method of Managed Bean.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to [Unable to execute Backing bean method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867947/unable-to-execute-backing-bean-method?rq=1)  with the answer "When i made it Session scoped its working Fine."
Does this work for you, too?

Answer (score 0):

try using actionListener instead of action to call the method when press p:command button